# Can we find a palindrome for more than $5$ factors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, products, arithmetic-progressions, palindrome

For positive integers $a,b$ and $k$ , define $$p(a,b,k):=\prod_{j=1}^k (a(j-1)+b)$$ That is the product of the first $k$ numbers in the arithmetic progression $an+b$ starting with $b$

> Can $p(a,b,k)$ be a palindrome (in base $10$) for $k\ge 6$ ? Are there more than $2$ palindromes for $k= 5$ ?

In the case $k=4$ , there are still many palindromes.

For $a,b\le 10^4$ , they are summarized in this table :

```
4   [7, 9, 11, 13]  9009
4   [12, 14, 16, 18]  48384
4   [1, 5, 9, 13]  585
4   [91, 101, 111, 121]  123444321
4   [11, 26, 41, 56]  656656
4   [26, 42, 58, 74]  4686864
4   [1023, 1073, 1123, 1173]  1445949495441
4   [9901, 10001, 10101, 10201]  10203040404030201
4   [127, 245, 363, 481]  5432772345
4   [1059, 1407, 1755, 2103]  5499287829945
4   [471, 961, 1451, 1941]  1274785874721
4   [55, 583, 1111, 1639]  58388088385
4   [13, 543, 1073, 1603]  12141614121
4   [1864, 2428, 2992, 3556]  48152399325184
4   [8841, 9497, 10153, 10809]  9214414224144129
4   [77, 1111, 2145, 3179]  583341143385
```

But for $5\le k\le 20$ and the same range for $a,b$ , there are just the following two solutions :

```
5   [31, 33, 35, 37, 39]  51666615
5   [182, 362, 542, 722, 902]  23255355355232
```

For $k\ge 5$ , the following can be said about the difference $a$ :

- If $a$ is coprime to $10$ , one of the factors of the product must be divisible by $5$ and the product is even, hence divisible by $10$. A palindrome is hence impossible.
- If $a$ is even , but not divisible by $5$ , one of the factors must be divisible by $5$ , hence the only possible palindrome is $5\cdots 5$, in particular all factors must be odd.

But that's it. I found no more useful necessary conditions for a palindrome.

Comment: Taking from the palindrome $1123211$ the product $11\cdot23\cdot2\cdot11$ we get the palindrome $5566$. It is the number of letters (forming $1247$ words) used in the  most singular novel of the XX century written by the french Georges Perec. This novel is a very large palindrome which, of course, can be read from the end to the begin (reading from right to left) if you want. This novel is nowadays known as “Palindrome” but was edited  in 1969 with another palindromic title.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be particularly useful information but for $k = 6$, any such palindrome has to be of the form $14n+7$ or $14n+13$

Comment: Let $p$ be the largest prime $\le k$. Then, any such palindrome is divisible by product $5.7.11 \ldots p$

Comment: Using a brute-force search: for the case $k=5$ the palindrome must have at least $31$ digits, for $k=6$ at least $37$ and for $7\leq k \leq 20$ at least $39$. The two palindromes for $k=5$ that you found may very well be the only ones for $k \geq 5$.